# Object info "Vertex Normal" for texture projecting in shader node on objeckts

Tags: texturing, faces, normals, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I'm trying to use Blenders Shader Nodes (or maybe it's possible with Geometry Nodes?) to project textures on objects similar how it in 3D-Coat works.

This is how 3D-Coats projects a simple brick texture on this objects
[image]

I can't do it that way in Blender. For this I would need the info of the face normal.
In Blender it looks like this for example. Pretty crooked.

[image]

I made that this way in Blender. Is there a way to make it with Blender 3.1 so that it looks similar to 3D-Coat?
[image]

Comment: The projection you want is built into image texture nodes as "box" (rather than "flat") mapping, with a "blend" greater than 0.  Check it out, you probably don't have to build anything.  You can't get the *vertex* normals for your samples, but you can get the sample's interpolated face normal or the true face normal, with geometry/normal and geometry/true normal respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first image look like box projection. The image texture node already has that built-in.

[image: shader nodes]

Comment: I looked at the brick and immediately though it's Brick Texture rather than Image Texture node :D Still there is a subtle difference - I added a comparison to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

[image]

Comparison with Aryan's answer - the one with bigger top is mine:

[image]

The below reproduces box projection except it flips the direction of some sides:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is much more flexible. You can use it with procedural textures and image textures alike. Can you try threshold value of 0.707 = 1 / sqrt(2) on the top Greater Than node. I think that should make it equivalent to box projection, and have less stretching (near top face B8 UV box)

Comment: @ShantanuAryan https://i.imgur.com/YGwctwT.png

Comment: Looks great : )

Comment: @ShantanuAryan See edit :)

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how I can get the face normal

[image]

I get this result. It's better but still not good

[image]