# How does image texture box mapping blend work?

Tags: texturing, image, vector-mapping

When I use an image texture with box mapping it gives me a blend value. When I increase the blend value it blends the texture at the seams.
How does this work? Does it do a rgbMix Mix operation based on the normals?

Texture:
[image]

Mapped on beveled box:
[image]

Mapped on Suzanne:
[image]

Comment: I reproduce box mapping here: [Object info "Vertex Normal" for texture projecting in shader node on objeckts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/262919/60486) - might be useful for testing.